# The import cucumber cannot be resolved in Runner Class for Gradle Project

Tags: gradle, junit, automation, cucumber

I don't whats wrong with my Gradle Dependencies but when I try to import `import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;` then I get error `The import cucumber cannot be resolved`

Below is my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '1.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-picocontainer', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-guice', version: '1.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'      
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

My Runner Class is:

```
package Runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
Cucumber.options(
    features = "\\src\\test\\java\\Feature",
    glue = {"\\src\\main\\java\\Steps\\"},
    tags = {"@ignored"},
    format = {"json:target/cucumber/wikipedia.json","html:target/cucumber/wikipedia.html","pretty"}
)
public class RunnerMain {
}
```

When I comment `@RunWith`, `CucumberOptions` and remove the imports, then run command `gradle build` then I don't see any error and all goes well.

I don't know what wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Cucumber.options with @CucumberOptions and try once